# After installing PowerShell-7.4.1-win-x64.msi, $PSVersionTable still shows 5.1.22621.2506

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-v5.0

I have installed PowerShell-7.4.1-win-x64.msi, but `$PSVersionTable` still shows version 5:

```
PS C:\Users\firerose> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                        
----                           -----                                                        
PSVersion                      5.1.22621.2506                                               
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                      
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                      
BuildVersion                   10.0.22621.2506                                              
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                              
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                          
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                          
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                      



PS C:\Users\firerose>
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of the application in the Start menu is *PowerShell 7 (x64)* instead of *Windows PowerShell*.

```
PowerShell 7.4.1
PS C:\Users\firerose> $PSBoundParameters
PS C:\Users\firerose> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      4      1

PS C:\Users\firerose>
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed both versions 5.1 and 7.4 are installed and run "side-by-side". That information is for the 5.1 installation, which is considered bundled with and part of Windows starting with Windows 10.0.14393 (1607)/ Windows Server 2016. You're probably looking for `pwsh.exe`.

Versions prior to 5.1 were installable or updated as part of the Windows Management Framework.

---

"PowerShell 7.4 installs to a new directory and runs side-by-side with Windows PowerShell 5.1."

"PowerShell 7.4 is an in-place upgrade that removes previous versions of *PowerShell 7*. Preview versions of PowerShell can be installed side-by-side with other versions of PowerShell."

"PowerShell 7.4 is installed to:  `$env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\7`"

"The `$env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\7` folder is added to $env:PATH"

**Installing PowerShell on Windows**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.4#installing-the-msi-package

**Migrating from Windows PowerShell 5.1 to PowerShell 7**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/migrating-from-windows-powershell-51-to-powershell-7?view=powershell-7.4

**PowerShell Versions**

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#Windows_PowerShell_5.1